# PySpark Dynamic Join Condition

Tags: join, dynamic, pyspark, conditional-statements

I have list of PK columns. I am storing primary keys because the number of primary keys for each table might change.  I want to join two data frames on the basis of the columns in `pk_list`.

```
pk_list=['col1',col2', .... 'coln']
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
full_load_tbl_nc = full_load_tbl.join(delta_load_tbl, (col(f) == col(s) for (f,s) in zip(pk_list,pk_list) ) , "leftanti")
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> casting list pyspark.sql.column also fails col(pk_list)
>   with import from pyspark.sql.functions import col 
>   File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1544185829274_0001/container_1544185829274_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 818, in join
>   AssertionError: on should be Column or list of Column

Comment: This question needs a [MCVE].

Comment: `join` in `pyspark` accepts a list of columns to join on as a parameter.  Is there a reason you cannot just do `full_load_tbl.join(delta_load_tbl, pk_list, how="leftanti")`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact, it will and all the columns in the list. I tested it and it works for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass keys for join as a List :  Try Below Code

```
DF1_Columns = ['col1',col2']
DF2_Columns = ['Col11', 'Col22']
result = DF1.join(DF2, ([col(f) == col(s) for (f,s) in zip(DF1_Columns ,DF2_Columns )]) , "type")
```

or you may write the same join statement as below if the names of the Key columns in both dataframes are similar :

```
result= DF1.join(DF2, ([col(column) == col(column) for column in DF1_Columns ]) , "type")
```